# Process.WaitForExit(Int32)

Tags: c#, process

Right now I am working on a Console Runner application that has the following code to output the log and to wait until the process is completed:

```
using (Process p = Process.Start(ps))
{
    p.OutputDataReceived += OutputReceived;
    p.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorReceived;
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.WaitForExit(30000);
    return p.ExitCode;
}
```

I have two questions about this piece of code.

1. I noticed that if the process takes longer than 30 seconds, the call p.ExitCode bombs.
2. What happens if my process takes only 1 second, will it wait 30 seconds anyway or the process will be advised by the CLR?

Comment: They hide these secrets in the documentation: *"If you try to get the ExitCode before the process has exited, the attempt throws an exception. Examine the HasExited property first to verify whether the associated process has terminated.*" and *"WaitForExit ... and blocks the current thread of execution until the time has elapsed or the process has exited"*

Comment: I found it too but I wasn't sure I read it properly.
So it seems that if the process exit before the timestamp inside the WaitForExit there are no problems but the other way around causes a nice exception.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx) of `ExitCode`:

> If you try to get the ExitCode before the process has exited, the attempt throws an exception. Examine the HasExited property first to verify whether the associated process has terminated.

There is no guarantee that when your call to `WaitForExit` returns, the process will have exited. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx) of `WaitForExit`:

> The WaitForExit(Int32) overload is used to make the current thread wait until the associated process terminates. This overload instructs the Process component to wait a finite amount of time for the process to exit. If the associated process does not exit by the end of the interval because the request to terminate is denied, false is returned to the calling procedure. You can specify a negative number (Infinite) for milliseconds, and Process.WaitForExit(Int32) will behave the same as the WaitForExit() overload. If you pass 0 (zero) to the method, it returns true only if the process has already exited; otherwise, it immediately returns false.

Note that this answers your second question. If the process exits before the timeout elapses, `WaitForExit` returns.

Since you specified a finite timeout, you allow for possibility of the function returning before the process has finished. So, you could write your code like this:

```
if (p.WaitForExit(30000))
    return p.ExitCode;
else
    return NotFinishedExitCode;
```

Or more concisely with a conditional expression:

```
return p.WaitForExit(30000) ? p.ExitCode : NotFinishedExitCode;
```

Comment: Thank you David for your explanation, I will give it a spin